# Error plugin not run in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a sample:

```
plugins
--shopping
  ----jcomments
  --------jcomment.php
  --------jcomment.xml
```

in plugins/shopping/jcomments/jcomment.php

```
class plgShoppingJcomments extends JPlugin
    function plgShoppingJcomments(&$subject, $config){ 
         parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    }
    function onBeforeDisplayProductView(&$view) {
         die('test');       
    }
}
```

And view.html.php of a component com_shopping I call

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('shopping');
$dispatcher =& JDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger( 'onBeforeDisplayProductView', $view);
```

But i run code is this plugin not show result (die("test")), how to fix this plugin

Comment: Does the plugin have parameters to set? - Is it enabled? - many are not when first installed.

Comment: what is your plugin group. is it show in backend plugin list. if not then try to store your plugin in any joomla group like system. then try to it or try to change your plugin folder name plg_jcomments,and plugin files jcomments.php, jcomments.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this... $dispatcher->trigger('onBeforeDisplayProductView', array($view)); (I'm only 60% sure this will work :D )